# Service Now GlideRecord query reference fields

Tags: servicenow

Does Service Now allow querying referenced fields through the GlideRecord?  And if so, how?

I have an application with a local user table for preferences specific to the application.  When a user fills out a new form, I would like to query the local user table to see if a record exists for the currently logged in user.  If it does, then I would like to prefill some of the answers on the form.

My user table has a reference to the sys_user table in order to link the local user record to the actual service now user.  When I try to run the script to check the local user table, it returns "sys_idNotValidnull" for the query statement I add.

```
var lscUser = new GlideRecord('x_wadm_lsc_user');
lscUser.addQuery('UserID', '=', gs.getUserID());
gs.info("Query: "+lscUser.getEncodedQuery());
lscUser.query();
```

Returns: "Query: sys_idNotValidnull"

If I change the query to search a different string field it works as expected.

```
var lscUser = new GlideRecord('x_wadm_lsc_user');
lscUser.addQuery('temp', '=', 'dan');
current.temp += "  Query: "+lscUser.getEncodedQuery();
```

Returns: "Query: temp=dan"

Comment: Are you sure your column name is actually "UserID"? Go check the element name in sys_dictionary to confirm. The behavior you're seeing is consistent with an invalid field name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with Dan that the first step should be to confirm the column names. I usually don't take anything for granted, and always double check. You can use the dictionary or right click on the field label and it will show the column name.

I have seen "sys_idNotValidnull", but usually only within scoped applications.

Comment: Although the column label was UserID, the actual column was u_reference_3.  Thanks for the assistance.